# get cookie content from an argument php

Tags: php, cookies

I have this cookie on set

```
    $id = "1"
    $password = "test";
    $cookie_name = "megamitch_server_status";
    $cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30); // 30 days
    setcookie ($cookie_name, 'usr='.$id.'&hash='.$password, time() + $cookie_time);
```

how I can get the value of usr inside that cookie name "megamitch_server_status"?

any help, ideas, suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: so far, what i tried is echo $_COOKIE['megamitch_server_status']['usr']; but  sadly, doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you :

(Here I just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to extract the data)

```
<?php

    preg_match_all("/usr=(.*)&hash=(.*)/", $_COOKIE["megamitch_server_status"], $matches);
    echo "usr: " . $matches[1][0];
    echo "hash: " . $matches[2][0];

?>
```

output:

```
usr: 1
hash: test
```

OR if you want you can store your cookies like this:

```
setcookie ($cookie_name . "[usr]", $id, time() + $cookie_time);
setcookie ($cookie_name . "[hash]", $password, time() + $cookie_time);
```

And then you can access them like this:

```
echo $_COOKIE["megamitch_server_status"]["usr"];
echo $_COOKIE["megamitch_server_status"]["hash"];
```

Comment: why in user, I got "=1"? its supposedly only "1".

Comment: @CodeDemon wups forgot to update my answer, now it should work for you